# React native image picking

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a React Native application, and I have a question. I'm developing a chat feature, and I want to add a functionality where when a chat bubble is clicked, a gallery slides in from both sides at the bottom of the text input. Additionally, I'd like to have a "View Fullscreen" button in the top right corner of the slide box so that when clicked, the gallery expands for a larger view. Can you please help me with this?

I tried using image picker and image crop picker, but they didn't work as I wanted them to.

Comment: Please Add Code what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make a custom gallery in your app? For that you need to use [CameraRoll library](https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll).

But If you wanted to change the appearance of the native image picker, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make a image gallery, you can use [react-native-cameraroll](https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll), but if you want to make a image picker, I think you have to create a custom library